# Passing constructor parameter to member in automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to use automapper and can't figure out how I can construct a member using a specific constructor and pass parameters to it. Basically I am trying to create mapping for parent object and I need to contruct the child object using same session instance as the parent object. I have gotten to point where the parent is being constucted using the proper constructor.

```
CreateMap<parentDto,parent>().ConstructUsing(p=>(parent)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(parent), new Session()));

//This works but child is created using different session instance than parent.
CreateMap<childDto,child>().ConstructUsing(c=>(child)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(child), new Session()));


class parentDto
{
    public childDto childDto{get;set;}
}

class child
{
  public child(Session session)
  {
  }
}

class parent
{
  public parent(Session session)
  {    
  }
  public child child{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Parameter of `ConstructUsing` is a function `source => destination`. That means you can say something like `.ConstructUsing(parentDto => new parent(session))`. And since I don't know what `Session` is in your case, I cannot help you further that this.

Comment: Session is an instance of https://docs.devexpress.com/XPO/DevExpress.Xpo.Session . The issue is that when converting parentdto to parent the created child-object needs to initiated using the same session object instance than parent.  I guess I'll write a custom typeconverter for this case.

Comment: You have a tough task ahead of you. I don't know how to help you. You can check whether you can do something with options parameter of `Map` method: `mapper.Map<ParentDto, Parent>(parentDto, opts => options.ConstructServicesUsing(...))`. Or somehow add it to configuration. I didn't use DevExpress, so I don't know how to work with `Session` object.

Comment: why don't you create one session variable and pass the same to both? `var session = new Session();` and then  `CreateMap<parentDto,parent>().ConstructUsing(p=>(parent)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(parent),session));` for parent and `CreateMap<childDto,child>().ConstructUsing(c=>(child)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(child), session));` for child

Comment: Am I missing something here?